# Windows - ping an ip via different interfaces

Tags: ping, tunnel, split-tunneling

I am working on Windows Server 2008/12.

I have two interfaces: a PPTP tunnel and the LAN card and I want to ping an IP via both of them to compare their results. As per the documentation, that should be possible via `ping -S default_gateway_for_interface`

Now this works when I pass the gateway for the default interface but I get

```
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
```

when I pass the PPTP tunnel's gateway. Any clues?

Comment: Did you set the source address?

Comment: Source address of what? If you mean in the ping request, yes. I did. I am passing the Server IPv4 address of the PPTP tunnel.

Comment: What is the actual ping command you use?

Comment: ping -S <server IPv4 address> 8.8.8.8

Comment: You are confusing me with the "default gateway" thing. The source address is the address on the device from which you are pinging, not the gateway for that subnet.

Comment: Suppose I have two addresses, `10.11.12.13` and `172.16.17.18` on my computer. I want to ping on the respective interfaces (logical or physical). I ping from the source (`-S`) with each of the addresses on my computer, not the gateways for those addresses.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. (I am very new to the networks world)

So, if I have to ping via the PPTP tunnel, the VPN connection gives me an IP titled 'Client IPv4 address'. Should I be using that? Because that didn't work either. So how would I know the other IP assigned to my computer?

Comment: For windows you can `ipconfig` to see all your IP addresses. If you are the VPN client, the client address is your address for the tunnel.

Comment: I get this via `ipconfig`: 

PPP adapter VPN Connection: 

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.253.xxx.xxx
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

And this is how I ping: 
 
`ping -S <192.253.xxx.xxx> 8.8.8.8` 

And this is the output I get: 

`Pinging 8.8.8.8 from 192.253.xxx.xxx with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.`

Comment: Can you ping from your VPN address to the address on the other end of the VPN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing me with the "default gateway" thing. The source address is the address on the device from which you are pinging, not the gateway for that subnet.

Suppose I have two addresses, 10.11.12.13 and 172.16.17.18 on my computer. I want to ping on the respective interfaces (logical or physical). I ping from the source (-S) with each of the addresses on my computer, not the gateways for those addresses.

For instance, I have a VPN tunnel and a physical interface on one of my computers, each with IP addresses.  The VPN doesn't allow me to ping outside the network on the other end of the tunnel.

Assume they are addressed like this: Tunnel=`172.16.17.18`, Ethernet=`10.11.12.13`.

```
 C:\>ping -S 10.11.12.13 time1.google.com

 pinging time1.google.com [216.239.32.15] from 10.11.12.13 with 32 bytes of data: 
 Reply from 216.239.32.15 bytes=32 time=21 ms TTL=43
 Reply from 216.239.32.15 bytes=32 time=22 ms TTL=43
 Reply from 216.239.32.15 bytes=32 time=23 ms TTL=43
 Reply from 216.239.32.15 bytes=32 time=22 ms TTL=43

 Ping statistics for 216.239.32.15:
     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
     Minimum = 21ms, Maximum = 23ms, Average = 22ms

 C:\>ping -S 172.16.17.18 time1.google.com

 pinging time1.google.com [216.239.32.15] from 172.16.17.18 with 32 bytes of data:
 Request timed out.
 Request timed out.
 Request timed out.
 Request timed out.

 Ping statistics for 216.239.32.15:
     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for going through the pains of posting this! I am doing the same thing. The issue must be because of the VPN then :)

Comment: I can ping from one end of my tunnel to the other, and I can ping anything on the rather large network on the other end of the tunnel, but I can't ping anything on the Internet from the tunnel because the network on the other end blocks that.

Comment: I tested and yes, the ping does go through when I try to ping the other end of tunnel via my IP. Thanks for explaining this concept :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add in the command line:
route ADD xxxx MASK xxx GatewayXXXX

In the place of GatewayXXXX, you put one gateway at time, next, delete the route and put the next one, accross the anothe link, changing the GatewayXXXX.

I think in that form, you can compare te results

Comment: Good advice! Not applicable in my case though because I have user data passing through the server and I want to first measure the performance of different routes for that particular IP by pinging them before creating the static routes (which will effect user data)